# what can be done to find out how to see who owns a gmail account and facebook account used to slander me

Tags: internet

I was the subject of an ABC news investigation against a unlicensed psychologist, the episode aired april 10th 2019, ABC attempted to interview the psychologist on april 8th approx 2:pm, less than an hour later ABC recieves an email from a bogus gmail account stating to the inteviewer that Im wanted by law enforcement for a host of things (all lies) and to vet me before airing the story. Now how did this bogus email know ABC inteviewed the psychologist if the special didn't air for two days? exactly its the psychologist (almost certain). Well the special air, then now a bogus facebook account pops up with an order of protection my ex wife tried to place on me (dismissed) to protect the therapist because they are friends and sorority sisters, welll this gmail address account and facebook account has caused me to almost loose my job, along with damaging to my credibility. So what can i do or instruct a lawyer to do to be able to verify who is behind the accounts? If intrested I am glad to share the ABC news interview along with the psychology board case against the unlicensed therapist.

Answer (score 0):

### If you take legal action, you can subpoena he records

It’s possible that you have a case for defamation from the email (assuming you *aren’t* actually wanted). I can’t see one from the Facebook post because you were subject to a protection order application so that is true - unless they stated that it had actually been granted.

Talk to a lawyer to see if it’s worth pursuing.

Comment: No not wanted at all, clean record, when the story came out april 10th they started doing this, because of that lie the account stated "this is floating around on the job" and showed copies of the order, but it was laughed out of court because my ex wife claimed 20 years of abuse and there were none, she hoped that bogus order would make me look bad and leave the therapist alone.

Comment: https://psychboard.az.gov/powers-marilyn-phd

Comment: https://www.abc15.com/news/impostor-doctors/man-warns-of-unlicensed-clinical-psychologist